# Python's win32com not closing?

Tags: python, win32com

I'm trying to close an Excel sheet that I have open using win32com, but the following code doesn't work:

```
from win32com import DispatchEx
xlApp = client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(str(main_folder) + "\\Original.xlsm")
ws = books.Worksheets["Sheet 1"]
ws.Visible = 1
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, str(main_folder) + "\\Duplicated")
ws.Close()
```

I get the following error:

```
"AttributeError: .Close"
```

How should I solve this?

Comment: Worksheet doesn't have a close method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet

Comment: Yes. You need to close your Workbook-Object!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to close the workook, you can do:

```
from win32com import DispatchEx
xlApp = client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(str(main_folder) + "\\Original.xlsm")
ws = books.Worksheets["Sheet 1"]
ws.Visible = 1
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, str(main_folder) + "\\Duplicated")
books.Close()  # changed line, use books instead of ws.
```

You can also see [xlwings](https://xlwings.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) if you have lots of things to do with Excel.

Answer (score -1):

> Please use the below command to close the excel application.

> **xlApp.Quit()**